# handleOpenURL method. Present modalviewcontroller and pass url info

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates, appdelegate

I'm having some trouble with the handleOpenURL method in my app delegate.  I have a rootviewcontroller that should be shown normally, but when a file is opened in my app, I need the handleOpenURL method to present a new viewcontroller and send the url info.  The problem is I can't present a modal view controller from my app delegate.  Also, when I try to call a method in my rootviewcontroller to present the modalviewcontroller I get

```
 Warning: Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

So, I guess I'm just looking for a solution that will present a new modal view controller and pass the url information to that class.  This is the app delegate method.

```
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you want to create the custom URL Schemes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your RootViewController,Create an instance of appDelegate just like

```
 YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.rootViewControllerInstance = self;
```

then subject

```
[appDelegate handleOpenURL:yourURL];
```

also create a callBackFunction eg:

`-(void)callBack:(NSUrl *)url;`

Now in appDelegate class create a `property` of your `RootViewController`

and in `appDelegate`  your function as specified this way..

```
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
[rootViewControllerInstance callBackUrl:url];
}
```

Comment: I can see what is supposed to happen but I can't quite get it to work.  Has anyone found a longer example?

Answer (score 1):

1. In storyboard, add the view controller you want to present by adding a new view controller and setting its class to the one you are presenting.
2. Control-drag from the root view controller to the new controller, which will create a `segue`.
3. Set a name for the `identifier` of the segue, customize it to be shown modally.
4. In root view controller, call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier"];`.
5. In `prepareForSegue` of the root view controller set any attributes, including e.g. a URL.